# <ul> not scrolling in IE10

Tags: touch, internet-explorer-10

Consider the following:

```
<ul onmouseover="javascript:this.style.overflowY='auto';" onmouseout="javascript:this.style.overflowY='hidden'" id="chatwindow" class="replies" style="overflow-y:hidden;height:90%">
```

Nothing fancy, just a scrolling UL that hides its scrollbar when the mouse is elsewhere. Works in every browser. On a Windows 8 tablet with IE10, the scrollbar appears (and stays in view) as long as I keep my finger on the UL. However, the UL refuses to scroll. I've tried -ms-touch-action:none and -ms-touch-action:pan-y to no avail. Without the onmouseover/onmouseout events, scrolling is as expected. Any clues?

Comment: You might want to note in your title/tags that this is related to touch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just plain CSS? Remove the events and use this:

```
#chatwindow {overflow:hidden}
#chatwindow:hover {overflow:auto}
```

If this doesn't work, I would suggest just not hiding the scrollbar - it's not a good idea from a user-interface point of view - after all, how would I know it's scrollable unless I happen to move the mouse over it? It would be very counterintuitive. Also, the scrollbar's appearance may cause layout issues, like how in YouTube Playlists sometimes the name of a video is suddenly on two lines because of the scrollbar appearing.

Comment: You're right about using CSS instead of javascript (damnit Jim, I'm a developer, not a designer!). The scrollbar IS causing layout issues in IE9, I've not come to that part yet, for now the touch scrolling is the problem I need to tackle. Thank you for your feedback though.